# XmlSerializer attribute not valid in Web Service using WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

I'm using WSCF.blue for generating the web service classes based on the WSDL and xsd. Calling the web service I receive the following error:

`"XmlSerializer attribute System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute is not valid in Email. Only XmlElement, XmlArray, XmlArrayItem, XmlAnyAttribute and XmlAnyElement attributes are supported when IsWrapped is true."`

I'm getting the same result using `svcutil.exe`. (VS 2010, .NET Framework 3.5)

Anybody ever heard about this problem?

Generating the code using `WSDL.exe` (old web service .NET 2.0) gets me the expected result but the return value is always from type object where as the WSCF.blue gets me a specific return object (e.g. ResponseProfileDto instead of object)

One of the class definitions looks like the following:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="ResendEmailRequest", WrapperNamespace="http://xy.com/test", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class ResendEmailRequest
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://xy.com/test", Order = 0, Name = "Email")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Email;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://xy.com/test", Order = 1, Name = "LoginName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string LoginName;

    public ResendEmailRequest()
    {
    }

    public ResendEmailRequest(string Email, string LoginName)
    {
        this.Email = Email;
        this.LoginName = LoginName;
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `/wrapped` attribute to create the code with the `svcutil`.

Hope this helps

Comment: In .net core command is: dotnet-svcutil --wrapped <url>