# WCF Webservice always returning null

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

I am consuming a SOAP webservice from our ticket system OTRS. So the Webservice is not really under my control. 
The request works just fine, but i am never getting an answer in my Code. The answer is always null. (`var response = client.SessionCreate(session);`)
The strange thing is, that wireshark and the webservice console of that ticket system are saying that i should receive a valid answer. 
Since i am very new to this webservice stuff so i have absolutely no idea where to start in this case. So here is a description of that i did. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

First i created a normal C# project and added the WSDL file which can be found only on the GitHub site website of the OTRS project. I added it as a Service Reference and than added my C# code which looks like this.

// For Debug
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");

```
try
{
    OTRS.OTRS_Error err = new OTRS.OTRS_Error();
    OTRS.GenericTicketConnector_PortTypeClient client = new OTRS.GenericTicketConnector_PortTypeClient("GenericTicketConnector_Port");

    OTRS.SessionCreate session = new OTRS.SessionCreate();
    session.Item = "someUserNameGoesHere";
    session.ItemElementName = OTRS.ItemChoiceType8.UserLogin;
    session.Password = "SomePasswordGoesHere";

    var response = client.SessionCreate(session);

    Console.WriteLine(response.SessionID);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Error);
}
catch (Exception exep) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(exep.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(exep.InnerException);
}
finally 
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Incoming message at serverside

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/SessionCreate</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:14750529-3de2-4618-8db4-8ac18b681c18</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
        <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://SomeServer/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnector</a:To>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SessionCreate xmlns="http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/">
        <UserLogin xmlns="">someUserName</UserLogin>
        <Password xmlns="">somePassword</Password>
    </SessionCreate>
</s:Body>
```

Outgoing message at serverside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" 
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <SessionCreateResponse xmlns="http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/">
            <SessionID>SomeSessionID</SessionID>
        </SessionCreateResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Wireshark HTTP/XML package going from the server to my client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" 
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <SessionCreateResponse xmlns="http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/">
            <SessionID>SomeSessionID</SessionID>
        </SessionCreateResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Refernce.cs
https://gist.github.com/HansVader/1ba3847d918ee15ef16703c8ada6c9bf

WSDL
https://gist.github.com/HansVader/dd849e49f4a1584397cd21b0e430b301

I currently only need the SessionnCreate and TicketUpdate function. The other operations are irrelevant at this point in time. Please let me know if you need any other informations.

Update:

Here are the traces from the trace tool like yildizm85 suggested in the comments:
[image: Outgoing SOAP message]

[image: Incoming SOAP message]

I think it is also worth noting that i created the `refernce.cs`
by myself with the `svcutil` tool because i had a problem with the IsWrapped. Have a look at this question and answer: 
[XmlSerializer attribute not valid in Web Service using WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689048/xmlserializer-attribute-not-valid-in-web-service-using-wcf)

Comment: Have you tried WCF tracing? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx

Comment: It looks like the message you send is correct, and the message you get back. I checked the namespaces a bit and it looks alright at a first sight. However, the deserialization doesn't seem to work, so probably something is generated wrong from the WSDL, or the WSDL is wrong. Have you tried to add the service reference multiple times (add and delete), or changed anything in reference.cs ?

Comment: Suggest you look at ServiceStack.net - really good web-service library. They have an older open source version at the bottom of their Download page.

Comment: Thanks for the answers this far. Please have a look at the updated question. I added the fact that i created the `reference.cs` by myself. Maybe there lies the error.

Answer (score 1):

The WSDL does not define elementFormDefault:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Since unqualified is default, this causes every property to be decorated with Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified in the generated reference file.

But, since there is a default namespace specified for each complex object, the XML serializer will not process the unqualified properties.

**The solution**

Change the schema element to:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

Also, for some of the properties, the order is wrong, so they need to be changed to (for example TickerCreateResponse):

```
<xsd:element name="TicketCreateResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="ArticleID" type="xsd:positiveInteger"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="TicketID" type="xsd:positiveInteger"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="TicketNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Error" type="tns:OTRS_Error"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

After these changes, create the proxy using svcutil:

svcutil.exe /serializer:XmlSerializer GenericTicketConnectorSOAP.wsdl /o:OtrsConnector.cs /wrapped /n:*,otrs

And using the config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="GenericTicketConnector_Binding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8" />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnector"
    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="GenericTicketConnector_Binding"
    contract="otrs.GenericTicketConnector_PortType" name="GenericTicketConnector_Port" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

It should work after that, at least it did for me.

Hope it works for you as well!